# Using v-autocomplete in a v-for loop results in a endless loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a the following setup:

```js
<template>
  <div>
  <div v-for="(participant, i) in participants" :key="`participant-${i}`">
   <v-autocomplete
     label="Search person"
     v-model="selected_persons[i]"
     outlined
     dense
     return-object
     cache-items
     :items="persons"
     @change="event => someMethod(event, i)"
     :search-input.sync="person"
     item-text="full_name"
     item-value="person_id"
     hide-details
   />
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data()
{
  return {
    person: null,
    persons: [],
    selected_persons: [],
    participants: [
       {
          person_id: 1,
          full_name: 'John Doe'
        },
        {
          person_id: 2,
          full_name: 'Jane Doe'
        }
    ]
  }
},
watch: {
   person(value)
   {
        value && value.length > 2 && this.queryPersons({search: value});
   },
},
methods: {
}
   async queryPersons(search)
   {
      let response = await fetch(route('search.persons', search));
       this.persons = await response.json();
     },
}
</script>
```

When the autocomplete is used for both `participants` this ends up in an endless loop of `update:search-input`[image]. The real problem here seems to be that you can't add a index to `:search-input.sync="person"`. So my question is how can I use a autocomplete in a `v-for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a watcher you can use an array and method on the `@update:search-input` event like the following:

```js
<template>
  <div>
  <div v-for="(participant, i) in participants" :key="`participant-${i}`">
   <v-autocomplete
        label="Person search"
        v-model="selected_persons[i]"
        outlined
        dense
        return-object
        cache-items
       :items="persons"
       @change="event => addPersonToPossibleParticipants(event, i)"
       :search-input.sync="person && person.length > 0 ? person[i] : null"
        @update:search-input="event => searchPerson(event, i)"
        item-text="full_name"
        item-value="person_id"
        hide-details
   />
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data()
{
  return {
    person: null,
    persons: [],
    selected_persons: [],
    participants: [
       {
          person_id: 1,
          full_name: 'John Doe'
        },
        {
          person_id: 2,
          full_name: 'Jane Doe'
        }
    ]
  }
},
methods: {
}
   async queryPersons(search)
   {
      let response = await fetch(route('search.persons', search));
       this.persons = await response.json();
     },

     searchPerson(value, index)
     {
        this.person[index] = value;

        if(value && value.length > 2) {
          this.queryPersons({search: value});
        }
      },
}
</script>
```